# Laravel set checkboxes checked based on database value

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to set checkboxes checked based on database value. One user can have have multiple checkbox values.

Checkboxes are generated from database table called `child_age_groups`:

```
   @foreach ($child_age_groups as $age)
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-info checkbox-inline">
         <input class="age_group_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="age_group[]" id="age_group{{$age->id}}" "/>
        <label for="age_group{{$age->id}}">{{$age->age_group}}</label>
     </div>
  @endforeach
```

So in my controller I get all the options that user has like this

```
  $nanny_babysitting_ages      = Nanny_babysitting_ages::where('user_id', user()->id)->get();
```

My nanny_babysitting_ages table is this

```
user_id | ages
```

and my child_age_groups table where I populate the checkboxes are this:

```
id | age_group
```

How can I set the checkboxes selcted based on the values from database?

Comment: Just use simple inline `if` in input like this : `@if($age==$nanny_babysitting_ages->age ) CHECKED @endif`

Comment: @Saman Property [ages] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: this is dirty work but if not passed `$nanny_babysitting_ages` from controller you can get `$nanny_babysitting_ages` in view with something like : `/App/Nanny_babysitting_ages::where('user_id', user()->id)->get();`

Comment: I am passing it from controller like I wrote in my question

Comment: So why age property dosent exists??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I resolved it, I added foreach and if statement in the input to check if it the same value as from database:

```
             <div class="form-group" id="ageCheckboxes">
                @foreach ($child_age_groups as $age)
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-info checkbox-inline">
                   <input class="age_group_checkbox" type="checkbox" value="{{$age->id}}" name="age_group[]" id="age_group{{$age->id}}" @foreach ($nanny_babysitting_ages as $ages) @if($age->id == $ages->ages ) checked @endif @endforeach />
                   <label for="age_group{{$age->id}}">{{$age->age_group}}</label>
                </div>
                @endforeach
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this "@checked(true)" like :-
<input class="custom-control-input army" type="checkbox" id="customCheckbox1"  @checked($emp_plus->army != 0)>